# Adding an additional letter to paste0()

Tags: r

I was wondering if there is a way to add an additional `p` letter to my `paste0()` command below so that instead of (currently) printing out: `"p1-2" "p1-3" "p2-3"` [*notice the missing* `p` in the second element], my code prints out: `"p1-p2"`, `"p1-p3"`, `"p2-p3"`?

```
p <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
    p[[i]] <- rbeta(20, 2, 6)
}
paste0("p", combn(seq_along(p), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "-")) ## HERE ##
```

Comment: `combn(seq_along(p), 2, FUN = function(x){paste0('p', x[1], '-p', x[2])})`

Answer (score 3):

Paste the `p` on the input of `combn`, not the output:

```
combn(paste0("p", seq_along(p)), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "-")
# [1] "p1-p2" "p1-p3" "p2-p3"
```